# Jquery onclick not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, onclick

I have this code below, what I am trying to do is add an onclick event to the my button to run the ShowDetails function, I can see the attribute has been added, but when I click on the link, nothing happens, I am expecting to see my alert.

```
(function($){
        $(function(){
                function ShowDetails(){
                        alert('hjhjkhjkh');
                }
                $('a.woocommerce-main-image').attr("href", "#");
                $('a.woocommerce-main-image').attr("onclick", "javascript:ShowDetails()");
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes

1. You can combine the dom ready handler and the IIFE as below
2. Instead of using inlined click handler use [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to register the handler

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function ShowDetails() {
        alert('hjhjkhjkh');
    }
    $('a.woocommerce-main-image').attr("href", "#").click(ShowDetails);
});
```

Why it was not worked: since you were using inlined event handler the js engine was looking for the method `ShowDetails` in the global scope(`window`) but you created that method as a closure method within the dom ready handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
function ShowDetails(){  
alert('hjhjkhjkh');  
}  
$('a.woocommerce-main-image').attr("href", "#");  
$('a.woocommerce-main-image').click(function(){  
ShowDetails();  
});  
});
```